# Rails error with rspec: "expected valid? to return true, got false"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm new to rails, and after completing Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, I am trying to expand some of the functionality. I started by changing the microposts so that they collect more data.

When running a rspec test, I can't figure out why I am getting this error:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/models/micropost_spec.rb
...............F.....

Failures:

  1) Micropost 
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.57 seconds
21 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:46 # Micropost
```

**micropost_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Micropost do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(content: "Lorem ipsum", 
    title: "This is a test title", 
    privacy: "1", 
    groups: "This is a test Group", 
    loc1T: "21 Bond St. Toronto, Ontario",
    loc1Lat: "43.654653",
    loc1Lon: "-79.377627",
    loc2T: "21 Bond St. Toronto, Ontario",
    loc2Lat: "43.654653",
    loc2Lon: "-79.377627",
    startTime: "Jan 1, 2000 12:01:01",
    endTime: "Jan 2, 2000 12:01:01",
    imageURL: "http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/hdr-main.gif") 

    puts @micropost.errors.messages
   }

  #before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(title: "This is a test title") }
  #before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(privacy: "1") }
  #before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(groups: "This is a test Group") }
  #before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(loc1T: "21 Bond St. Toronto, Ontario") }
  #before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(loc1Lat: "43.654653") }
  #before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(loc1Lon: "-79.377627") }
  #before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(loc2T: "21 Bond St. Toronto, Ontario") }
  #before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(loc2Lat: "43.654653") }
  #before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(loc2Lon: "-79.377627") }
  #before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(startTime: "Jan 1, 2000 12:01:01") }
  #before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(endTime: "Jan 2, 2000 12:01:01") }
  #before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(imageURL: "http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/hdr-main.gif") }



  subject { @micropost }

  it { should respond_to(:content) }
  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:user) }

  it { should respond_to(:title) }
  it { should respond_to(:privacy) }
  it { should respond_to(:groups) }
  it { should respond_to(:loc1T) }
  it { should respond_to(:loc1Lat) }
  it { should respond_to(:loc1Lon) }
  it { should respond_to(:loc2T) }
  it { should respond_to(:loc2Lat) }
  it { should respond_to(:loc2Lon) }
  it { should respond_to(:startTime) }
  it { should respond_to(:endTime) }
  it { should respond_to(:imageURL) }



  its(:user) { should == user }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "accessible attributes" do
    it "should not allow access to user_id" do
      expect do
        Micropost.new(user_id: user.id)
      end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end    
  end

  describe "when user_id is not present" do
    before { @micropost.user_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "with blank content" do
    before { @micropost.content = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "with content that is too long" do
    before { @micropost.content = "a" * 141 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

**micropost.rb**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title,:privacy,:groups,:loc1T,:loc1Lat,:loc1Lon,:loc2T,:loc2Lat,:loc2Lon,:startTime,:endTime,:imageURL



  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :privacy, presence: true
  validates :groups, presence: true
  validates :loc1T, presence: true
  validates :loc1Lat, presence: true
  validates :loc1Lon, presence: true
  validates :loc2T, presence: true
  validates :loc2Lat, presence: true
  validates :loc2Lon, presence: true
  validates :startTime, presence: true
  validates :endTime, presence: true
  validates :imageURL, presence: true

  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }

  default_scope order: 'microposts.created_at DESC'

  def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                         WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", 
          user_id: user.id)
  end
end
```

**factories.rb**

```
    FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    #name     "Michael Hartl"
    #email    "michael@example.com"
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"} 
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end

   factory :micropost do
    content "Lorem ipsum"
    title "This is a test title"
    privacy "1"
    groups "This is a test Group"
    loc1T "21 Bond St. Toronto, Ontario"
    loc1Lat "43.654653"
    loc1Lon "-79.377627"
    loc2T "21 Bond St. Toronto, Ontario"
    loc2Lat "43.654653"
    loc2Lon "-79.377627"
    startTime "Jan 1, 2000 12:01:01"
    endTime "Jan 2, 2000 12:01:01"
    imageURL "http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/hdr-main.gif"

    user
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if there is anything else you need me to post.

Comment: can you puts value of micropost and check its value.

Comment: how do I put the value of micropost and check it's value?

Comment: use puts statement in some testcase and then run bundle exec rspec spec, it will print your micropost like ..........microspost: blah.F......

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm new to rails. I do not know which file to add the puts statement. What am I supposed to add to the file. Googling "puts statement" is not helping.

Comment: you know what puts do in rails

Comment: Your series of `before` blocks are each overwriting `@micropost`, so they're basically undoing each other. That's the first thing I'd fix. You have the same data in your factory so you should be using that.

Comment: Honestly, not to be discouraging, but you won't get any good answers here though because there are just too many problems with this code.

Comment: I commented out the before blocks and it passes now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got rid of the errors.

**micropost_spec.rb**

```
describe Micropost do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(content: "Lorem ipsum", 
    title: "This is a test title", 
    privacy: "1", 
    groups: "This is a test Group", 
    loc1T: "21 Bond St. Toronto, Ontario",
    loc1Lat: "43.654653",
    loc1Lon: "-79.377627",
    loc2T: "21 Bond St. Toronto, Ontario",
    loc2Lat: "43.654653",
    loc2Lon: "-79.377627",
    startTime: "Jan 1, 2000 12:01:01",
    endTime: "Jan 2, 2000 12:01:01",
    imageURL: "http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/hdr-main.gif") 

puts @micropost.errors.messages
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid because your model object is not passing your validations. In your `before` block, after you create `@micropost`, add this line to see which validations are failing

```
puts @micropost.errors.messages
```

There will be a hash of validations (fields and error messages) that have failed. Fix those and then your object will be valid. Some earlier commenters had suggestions on where to start to help fix the problem.

Comment: I did this, and it passes.
`before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(content: "Lorem ipsum", 
    title: "This is a test title", 
    privacy: "1", 
    groups: "This is a test Group", 
    loc1T: "21 Bond St. Toronto, Ontario",
    loc1Lat: "43.654653",
    loc1Lon: "-79.377627",
    loc2T: "21 Bond St. Toronto, Ontario",
    loc2Lat: "43.654653",
    loc2Lon: "-79.377627",
    startTime: "Jan 1, 2000 12:01:01",
    endTime: "Jan 2, 2000 12:01:01",
    imageURL: "http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/hdr-main.gif") 

puts @micropost.errors.messages
}`

Comment: @livi1717 Check the test.log. There might be more clues in the log as to why the object is not valid.